# i need redis high availability statistics

Tags: high-availability, redis

does anyone have any real life statistics on how long they can keep a Redis instance up and running for? I know I can get Redis Sentinel to give me fail over functionality but what is should be my expectation?

A single Redis instance 24x7?
A failure over setup with Redis Sentinel 24x7x365?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have about 250 redis instances running. Some are running for 816 days. I havn't seen a single instance crash so far (we have limited the commands a bit).

We are not using Redis Sentinel, but we wrote our own daemon doing the configuration management (realtime configuration changes, etc.), starting/stopping instances, etc. This daemon also starts a slave instance on a second server, but so far: the slave was not needed ;)